# PHPExcel memory exhausted

Tags: caching, memory-leaks, phpexcel

Im using PHPExcell to export 4000 rows with 20 columns. I wanted to color every second row in sheet, then i wrote a loop, but it returns me

`FAtal Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in D:\Data\xampp\htdocs\Classes\PHPExcel\Style\Supervisor.php`

I've been searching 2 hours to resolve problem but I failed. Every topic i found is pretty old, 2010 or earlier. I've tried to use caching, something liek this

```
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array( ' memoryCacheSize ' => '8MB');
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
```

But that doesn't help. Any idea how can i fix that problem?

And at the end my loop i use to generate xlsx and format cells:

```
$i = 2;
    foreach($table as $row){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $row[1])
                ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $row[2])
                ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $row[3])
                ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $row[4])
                ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $row[5])
                ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $row[6])
                ->setCellValue('G'.$i, $row[7])
                ->setCellValue('H'.$i, $row[8])
                ->setCellValue('I'.$i, $row[9])
                ->setCellValue('J'.$i, $row[10])
                ->setCellValue('K'.$i, $row[11])
                ->setCellValue('L'.$i, $row[12])
                ->setCellValue('M'.$i, $row[13])
                ->setCellValue('N'.$i, $row[14])
                ->setCellValue('O'.$i, $row[15])
                ->setCellValue('P'.$i, $row[16])
                ->setCellValue('Q'.$i, $row[17])
                ->setCellValue('R'.$i, $row[20])
                ->setCellValue('S'.$i, $row[21])
                ->setCellValue('T'.$i, $row[22]);
        // Color every second row
    if($i%2!=0){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$i.':T'.$i)->getFill()->applyFromArray(
    array(
    'type'       => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
    'startcolor' => array('rgb' => 'e8f4ff')
    ));
    }

    //color column "O"
    if($i%2==0){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('O'.$i)->getFill()->applyFromArray(
    array(
    'type'       => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
    'startcolor' => array('rgb' => 'fffacd')
    ));
    }
    else{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('O'.$i)->getFill()->applyFromArray(
    array(
    'type'       => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
    'startcolor' => array('rgb' => 'fff9bd')
    ));
    }

    // color column "N"
    if($i%2==0){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('N'.$i)->getFill()->applyFromArray(
    array(
    'type'       => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
    'startcolor' => array('rgb' => 'eaffee')
    ));
    }
    else{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('N'.$i)->getFill()->applyFromArray(
    array(
    'type'       => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
    'startcolor' => array('rgb' => 'ccffcc')
    ));
    }           


    $i++;
    }
```

EDIT:: I post full code coz i have no idea what more i can do. I create new phpexcel object and then import empty template only with 1st row as header with colnames. rest cells are totaly empty with preset style. I set style for 10 000 rows. But it still returns me same error. There's code:

```
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
        die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

    /** Include PHPExcel */
    require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';



    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objReader = $objReader->load('components/com_uhlist/Classes/template.xlsx');
    $template = $objReader->getActiveSheet();

    $objPHPExcel->addExternalSheet($template);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);

    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $username = $user->get('username');
    // Set document properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator($username)
                                 ->setLastModifiedBy($username)
                                 ->setTitle("User & Host List");



    // Add some data
    // Aktywowanie arkusza
    //$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(-0);


    // Export danych
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$db->getPrefix().'users_n_hosts';
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $table = $db->loadRowList();

    $i = 2;
    foreach($table as $row){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $row[1])
                ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $row[2])
                ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $row[3])
                ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $row[4])
                ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $row[5])
                ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $row[6])
                ->setCellValue('G'.$i, $row[7])
                ->setCellValue('H'.$i, $row[8])
                ->setCellValue('I'.$i, $row[9])
                ->setCellValue('J'.$i, $row[10])
                ->setCellValue('K'.$i, $row[11])
                ->setCellValue('L'.$i, $row[12])
                ->setCellValue('M'.$i, $row[13])
                ->setCellValue('N'.$i, $row[14])
                ->setCellValue('O'.$i, $row[15])
                ->setCellValue('P'.$i, $row[16])
                ->setCellValue('Q'.$i, $row[17])
                ->setCellValue('R'.$i, $row[20])
                ->setCellValue('S'.$i, $row[21])
                ->setCellValue('T'.$i, $row[22]);       
    $i++;
    }



    // Nazwa arkusza
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('User & Host');


    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="User&Host_'.date('d-m-Y').'.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;

    }
```

Newest Code:: Insert data into template:

```
            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcel->load('components/com_uhlist/Classes/template.xlsx');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $username = $user->get('username');
    // Set document properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator($username)
                                 ->setLastModifiedBy($username)
                                 ->setTitle("User & Host List");

    // Export danych
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$db->getPrefix().'autocad_users_n_hosts';
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $table = $db->loadRowList();

    $i = 2;
    foreach($table as $row){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $row[1])
                ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $row[2])
                ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $row[3])
                ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $row[4])
                ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $row[5])
                ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $row[6])
                ->setCellValue('G'.$i, $row[7])
                ->setCellValue('H'.$i, $row[8])
                ->setCellValue('I'.$i, $row[9])
                ->setCellValue('J'.$i, $row[10])
                ->setCellValue('K'.$i, $row[11])
                ->setCellValue('L'.$i, $row[12])
                ->setCellValue('M'.$i, $row[13])
                ->setCellValue('N'.$i, $row[14])
                ->setCellValue('O'.$i, $row[15])
                ->setCellValue('P'.$i, $row[16])
                ->setCellValue('Q'.$i, $row[17])
                ->setCellValue('R'.$i, $row[20])
                ->setCellValue('S'.$i, $row[21])
                ->setCellValue('T'.$i, $row[22]);       
    $i++;
    }

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="User&Host_'.date('d-m-Y').'.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
```

Comment: Note: should be  `memoryCacheSize` instead of  ` memoryCacheSize` (no space in front needed.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of the other caching methods? SQLite or SQLite 3 are the most memory efficient, because all other methods retain an in-memory cell index.

Wherever possible, apply your styling to a range of cells rather than to every individual cell. Range styling is far more memory efficient, and is the recommended approach
This is because it only creates a single style object for the specified range; while styling individual cells creates a style record for every individual usage.

Those are the two biggest memory reducing factors.

Creating an initial template with the styles already defined, and using the worksheets duplicateStyle() or duplicateStyleArray() methods may also help - especially as you can duplicate to a range of cells for your alternate rows - because this doesn't create new style objects but reuses the existing defined style objects.

Failing all that, you may still need to increase your php memory settings.

Comment: Hi Mark,thanks for reply. I edited my answer and i added my full code. I made template and then import that sheet to new object but i still have error. If u can take a look I would be grateful.

Comment: Well you can write directly to the template: the file on disk is only overwritten if you actively save to that file; and as you're saving to php://output that isn't an issue - that change would mean you only have one PHPExcel object file in memory.

Comment: What cell caching are you using in that updated code: the methods I suggested are ways to reduce memory usage, but they won't eliminate it; so using a template won't eliminate the need to use cell caching

Comment: I don't use any at this moment, thought that template would help. Should i try this?  `$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_in_sqlite;
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod); ` Correct this code if im wrong, coz im not sure its correct

Comment: `$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_sqlite3;
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod);
`

Comment: Posted newest code. Now im puting data directly to template, and saving to php output. Now i dont have memory problem, but after i download the file excel cant open it saying: incorrect format or file extension.

Comment: Already tested cache to sqlite3. It's not working. Maybe there's a way to style range rows, i mean every secong row, without using loop? like css :nth-child() pseudoclass?

Comment: Open in a text edit, and look for leading/trailing whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, newlines, or BOM headers); or for any obvious PHP error messages in the body of the file

Comment: And no, there is no nth-child pseudoclass equivalent

Comment: that incorrect file inside says: `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in <b>D:\Data\xampp\htdocs\Classes\PHPExcel\CachedObjectStorage\CacheBase.php'` Ok i think i`ll pass setting style for every cell. It's not a must and taking a lot of my time. I give up ;) Thank's for help.

Comment: Probably the fact that you're loading all your data into a PHP array before looping through it a row at a time doesn't help: that PHP array is using a lot of memory as well.... if you could fetch the data from the database a row at a time and write each row to the worksheet as you read it, then it would use less memory

Comment: I know this is ancient, but I just had this issue and setting the cache method as shown by @MarkBaker above fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PHP XLSXWriter](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter).  It's lightweight, and writes the xml sheets to disk as it goes, so in my experience is has much lower memory usage.  It cannot in any way read a spreadsheet, so while it isn't as powerful as phpexcel, it does a good job of writing.

The phpexcel library stores everything in memory before writing it all out, and by design it has high memory usage.